# How to create a chrome extension that will scrape data from a SAAS app where the code is encrypted?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to create a script, that will pull the data from a contact record in a SAAS CRM application and make it available when I am in another screen in the same SAAS CRM application.

The problem is the following:

When I place my mouse over the field, I can see the underlying parameters of the field, but when I look up that parameter in the source code, I can´t find the same data.  The contact data seems to be cloaked in the source code.

I am not looking to scrape a large number of records, I am just trying to get better access to the data that is available for a contact without having to open up 3 or 4 windows at the same time, and try to reduce the number of user clicks.

Is there a place I can go read to try to figure out how to emulate a user, and parse the data in a Google Chrome extension?

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the data is being populated via javascript or AJAX and thus not visible in the source code as when you "view source" you see it naked before any JS or dynamic elements take over. You should use a DOM explorer like firebug or even the inbuilt console debuggers of modern browers and not just "view source".

For example if you are using chrome, right click on the element on the page and select "inspect element" you should be able to see the HTML in its live form.

If you plan to scrape this data you will have to allow the javascript to be executed and any DOM or CSS changes to happen and then grab your data.

If the data is being populated via JS / AJAX you might be able to find the source of the data feed, if it is an AJAX call then the data is coming from another URL, you might be able to grab the data only from that URL.